# Constructive planarity testing

Tags: algorithm, optimization, graph-theory

I am writing an algorithm that is trying to build a planar graph.
I start with a planar graph, and have to add edges between n nodes so that I build a n-cycle, but do not disrupt the planarity. I know it is possible to do.

My idea is to randomly add edges until planarity is disrupted, and then start over, until I find the right set of edges. To do this I would have to do a lot of planarity testing.

I know the best algorithms are O(n), so I was wondering if there is an algorithm that would not need to start over each time I add an edge. **I mean if I just ran the algorithm on the same graph, with one edge less, could I somehow no redo all the steps?**

I understand planarity testing algorithms are difficult to implement, so ideally, I would prefer not to implement the whole thing myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Planarity testing algorithms often give a combinatorial embedding as a byproduct. You can operate directly on the faces of this embedding, adding enough non crossing chords to each, without needing to check for planarity.

If you have a planar straight line graph and want to maintain that structure, again find the faces and then use an algorithm to triangulate non convex polygons.